# C# MYSQL query every second

Tags: c#, mysql

So, I have a program I'm working on where more than one client is connected to a MYSQL Database and I want to keep them all current. When one client updated the database, the information in all clients updates. I'm new and still studying in college, so the only way I could think to do this is to make a column that held each records update time and then each second use this query:

```
if (sqlHandler.userLastUpdate < sqlHandler.LastUpdate())
        {

            //Loads the products from the Database
            sqlHandler.ReadDB();

            //Set's this clients last update time to now so it doesn't keep refreshing
            sqlHandler.userLastUpdate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        }


public double LastUpdate()
    {
        using var con = new MySqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT MAX(LastUpDate) FROM products";
        using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

        using MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        double time = rdr.GetDouble(0);

        return time;
    }
```

This seems horribly inefficient. Is there a better way to do this. I've had a couple clients running on the same MYSQL server and it seemed to be fine, but it just seems to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Look into mechanisms like sockets.  Sockets are a real-time communication mechanism that doesn't require the polling operations you described in your question.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr

Comment: Typically a pub/sub implementation is the right approach for this.  By having producers create a message and all subscribers receive a copy, you can avoid reading from the database entirely if you so choose.

Comment: I suppose what you need is that the one who makes the changes fires off some code which pushes the change to all the subscribers

Comment: yeah, pretty much, or just a signal that says "hey, I updated the database, pull the updated one"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the link, it gave me a great starting point. I ended up ussing RabbitMQ as the implemantation seemed simpler to me, but I never would of even though of some ort of MQ system if it weren't for you guys.